# Force clear standby memory and cache [ Windows 8 ]

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, cache

I love faster app loading , i really love it when i click an application and it is opened 3 seconds later , i do love it.

But for the love of god , i hate it when  i run a heavy program in my potato computer and it crashes / become laggy because the memory is full , and 60% of the memory is filled with standby memory and cache that does nothing except make program load faster and nothing else .

I use [RamMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap), and other memory cleaner, and the standby memory is still not be able to be cleared because these stupid background program somehow protect themself from getting their standby memory cleared away so they can load their program faster .

How do i completely empty standby memory ? i don't care anymore if it means i need 300% or 1000% longer time to load program , i just need free space at my memory .

Here is some picture :

1. [Me :**Trying to clear standby memory**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2uSf.jpg)
2. [Program that prioritize speed over memory : " hohoho , it is not that easy ferguso "](https://i.imgur.com/yRnMzDs_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium)

Edit : i found out that the only way to clear that standby memory is by uninstalling the program , but i don't want that , and also i already tried  https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/ and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try Empty Standby List https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/
Then I created a batch file which will automatically clear the standby memory every 5 minutes = 300 seconds (which can be adjusted to your own liking). I will let this run on the background (run as admin as well). This works with my Windows 7 Professional x64.
:loop
echo Clearing...
EmptyStandbyList.exe standbylist
timeout 300
cls
goto loop

Credit goes to Newbie Programmers on Super User, not sure if this helps I just googled and read stuff for 20 minutes trying to help. I did not know of a solution myself.

Comment: i forgot to mention i have tried that as well and the amount of standby memory used by installed program ( non-os program ) is not changing a bit except if i uninstall them . Thanks i appreciate the help but do you have any other way ?